# findall() or filter() functions with multiple conditions in julia 1.0.3

Tags: julia

I am trying to convert following python codes to julia 1.0.3

```
    from numpy import *
    xl,xr,yl,yr = 0,1,0,1
    xs,ys = linspace(xl,xr,N),linspace(yl,yr,N)

    x,y = np.meshgrid(xs,ys)
    data=column_stack((ravel(x),ravel(y)))     
    idx1 = where((data[:,0]==xl) | (data[:,0]==xr) | (data[:,1]==yl) | (data[:,1]==yr))
```

I could not convert last  row of the above codes. I came across `findall()` and `filter()` functions but could not use them properly in my case

Comment: Can you explain what your code should do? Not everyone is familiar with numpy, and this `where` line is not so easy to interpret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you want `data` to hold all pairs you can create from elements of `xs` and `ys` and select the indices of elements of `data` that are on the border to `idx1`. If this is the case this is how I would implement it in Julia:

```
n=11
xl, xr, yl, yr = 0,1,0,1
xs, ys = range(xl, stop=xr, length=n), range(xl, stop=xr, length=n)
data = [(x,y) for y in ys for x in xs]
idx1 = findall(((x,y),) -> x in (xl,xr) || y in (yl, yr), data)
```

If you want `data` to be a matrix not a vector you could do:

```
data2 = reduce(vcat, [x y] for y in ys for x in xs)
idx12 = filter(i -> data2[i,1] in (xl,xr) || data2[i,2] in (yl, yr), axes(data2, 1))
```

but in this case for me it would be more natural in Julia to use a vector of tuples rather than a matrix.

You can also consider using `Iterators.product` function to generate `data` like this `vec(collect(Iterators.product(xs, ys)))`.